# Is it possible to get right person_id from below tables?

Tags: mysql

I have one relationship table which has relationship between two person.

```
id personA personB description
1    1       3          X
2    4       1          Y
3    3       4          Z
4    1       3          W
5    1       4          V
```

I am not very good with MySQL but My requirement is to get relationship of particular person. Eg. Who is friend of person 1 without any duplicate entry. Over here person1 is friend of person 3 and person 4. I need answer as:

```
 person
    3
    4
```

I tried but failed miserably

```
SELECT DISTINCT personA,personB FROM tester.relationship where personA=1 OR personB=1;
```

It is printing personA & personB with duplicate value (1,4 & 4,1).

```
personA personB
1        3
4        1
1        4
```

Comment: why is one relationship duplicated in the source table (1 -> 4 && 4 -> 1) but not for another relationship, 1 -> 3 for instance? What does the `description` represent?

Comment: Description is just to represent relationship type like brother/Sister, Dr/Patient and yes you are right but right now this is what our table look like and we can't go and fix duplicate entry that's why I am currently looking for query :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union to do this. Here we SELECT for one direction of the relationship and then again for the other direction. UNIONing the results gives us distinct records:

```
SELECT personB FROM tester.relationship where personA=1 
UNION
SELECT personA FROM tester.relationship where personB=1;
```

Alternatively you could employ a CASE condition on your original query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN personA = 1 THEN personB ELSE personA END 
FROM tester.relationship 
WHERE personA=1 OR personB=1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day. Union solution is working for me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
                   WHEN personA = 1 THEN personB 
                   ELSE personA
                END
FROM relationship
WHERE 1 IN (personA, personB)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f2062/1)

Answer (score 0):

if you  are looking only for friend

```
 SELECT DISTINCT personB
 FROM tester.relationship 
 where personA=1
```

you don't need  OR personB = 1

Comment: Thanks but I want a single column having result as 3 & 4.